# Does $C^*(G) \cong C^*(H)$ imply that $\mathbb{C}G \cong \mathbb{C}H$?

Tags: operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

I wonder whether the underlying complex group algebra of a group $C^*$-algebra is unique? I.e. if $G$ and $H$ are discrete groups such that $C^*(G) \cong C^*(H)$ (or $C^*_r(G) \cong C^*_r(H)$) as $C^*$-algebras, does it follow that $\mathbb{C}G \cong \mathbb{C}H$ as complex $*$-algebras?

I know that this does not hold on the level of groups. Since $\mathbb{Z}_4 \ncong \mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2$, while their group $C^*$-algebras are both $\mathbb{C}^4$.

The reason I am interested in the discrete case is that then we have an underlying algebraic object, $\mathbb{C}G$, which is dense when endowed with the norm. I am interested in the uniqueness of such "dense underlying algebraic objects" in $C^*$-algebraic constructions.

Thanks!

Comment: Quite a lot of people wonder how unique the group $C^*$-algebra is. It's an important open problem to determine wither $C^*(F(n)) \cong C^*(F(m))$ for any $n,m>1$ (where here I mean these to be free groups); the group algebras are the noncommutative polynomial rings $\Bbb C\langle x_1, \dots, x_n\rangle$. But these are never isomorphic. So either your question is open or false; I suspect the latter. (I do not know $C^*$-algebras well enough to construct a counterexample.)

Comment: If the groups aren't discrete then what do you mean by their group algebras?

Comment: Thanks! I have realized that the complex group algebra does not have anything to do with the group $C^*$-algebra in the non-discrete case, since then we are using integrals against Haar measure rather than sums. The question has now been modified.

Comment: @Mike: the group algebras aren't quite the noncommutative polynomial rings; you need to invert the generators. But yes, these are never isomorphic, and can be distinguished e.g. by the Krull dimension of their abelianizations.

Answer (score 4):

Suppose $G$ and $H$ are abelian. Then their group C*-algebras are isomorphic iff their Pontryagin duals are homeomorphic. So take, for example, $G$ to be the Prufer 2-group and $H$ to be the Prufer 3-group. Their Pontryagin duals are the 2-adic and 3-adic integers, which are homeomorphic but not isomorphic even as abstract groups. I'm not sure off the top of my head if the group algebras are isomorphic though. But I suspect they can be distinguished by their self-adjoint subalgebras.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! I will have a look at it and see if I can confirm that their group algebras are non-isomorphic.

Comment: I'm not able to show that the group algebras are non-isomorphic. Do you know of any tools I can look up which might help me do this?

Comment: @Pjolter: I don't know. They might just be isomorphic...